# How can I calculate the 95th percentile over a table with numpy?

Tags: python, numpy, percentile

I am trying to calculate the 95th percentile and other percentiles from my table using numpy. However the function to do this seems unclear to me since it needs an array for it to work:

```
>>> a = np.array([[10, 7, 4], [3, 2, 1]])
>>> a
array([[10,  7,  4],
       [ 3,  2,  1]])
>>> np.percentile(a, 50)
```

That would be the way for the 50th percentile over an array.

Here is how my table looks like:

```
Date        Hour    Month       Value
9/1/2019    0:00    SEPTEMBER   377.3333333
9/1/2019    0:00    SEPTEMBER   268.8
9/1/2019    0:00    SEPTEMBER   400.8
9/1/2019    0:00    SEPTEMBER   279.1304348
9/1/2019    0:05    SEPTEMBER   440
9/1/2019    0:05    SEPTEMBER   228
9/1/2019    0:05    SEPTEMBER   350
9/1/2019    0:05    SEPTEMBER   283.2
9/1/2019    0:10    SEPTEMBER   385.3333333
9/1/2019    0:10    SEPTEMBER   240
9/1/2019    0:10    SEPTEMBER   347.5
9/1/2019    0:10    SEPTEMBER   175.2
9/1/2019    0:15    SEPTEMBER   440
9/1/2019    0:15    SEPTEMBER   202.8
9/1/2019    0:15    SEPTEMBER   204
9/1/2019    0:15    SEPTEMBER   182.4
...
9/2/2019    0:00    SEPTEMBER   416
9/2/2019    0:00    SEPTEMBER   134.4
9/2/2019    0:00    SEPTEMBER   370
...
```

Until the end of September

I want to calculate the 95th percentile for every 5min interval.

The final result should be something like:

```
Time    September
0:00    95th Value
0:05    95th Value
0:10    95th Value
0:15    95th Value
```

....

Comment: Can you use pandas instead of numpy? If you load your table in a dataframe, the solution is just `dataframe.groupby(['Hour', 'Month'])['Value'].quantile(0.95)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
import re
import pandas as pd

data = '''9/1/2019    0:00    SEPTEMBER   377.3333333
9/1/2019    0:00    SEPTEMBER   268.8
9/1/2019    0:00    SEPTEMBER   400.8
9/1/2019    0:00    SEPTEMBER   279.1304348
9/1/2019    0:05    SEPTEMBER   440
9/1/2019    0:05    SEPTEMBER   228
9/1/2019    0:05    SEPTEMBER   350
9/1/2019    0:05    SEPTEMBER   283.2
9/1/2019    0:10    SEPTEMBER   385.3333333
9/1/2019    0:10    SEPTEMBER   240
9/1/2019    0:10    SEPTEMBER   347.5
9/1/2019    0:10    SEPTEMBER   175.2
9/1/2019    0:15    SEPTEMBER   440
9/1/2019    0:15    SEPTEMBER   202.8
9/1/2019    0:15    SEPTEMBER   204
9/1/2019    0:15    SEPTEMBER   182.4
9/1/2019    0:20    SEPTEMBER   416
9/1/2019    0:20    SEPTEMBER   134.4
9/1/2019    0:20    SEPTEMBER   370
9/2/2019    0:05    SEPTEMBER   145.9
9/2/2019    0:05    SEPTEMBER   360'''

data = [re.split('[ ]+', x) for x in data.split('\n')]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['date','hour','month','value'])
df['value'] = df['value'].astype(float)
print(df.groupby(['date','hour']).value.quantile(0.95))
```

Comment: Do you know how can I transform the result into a data frame again?

Comment: Instead of printing, assign the groupby statement into a variable and then call the .to_frame() method on that variable.

Comment: I used reset.index(). Does this produce the same result or I you think I will have issues if I continue.